# OS X - Can I change the dimensions of a NSViewController programmatically?

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoa, resize, nsviewcontroller

I am using Cocoa and I have a NSViewController with the dimensions set. However, I want to programmatically change the dimensions based on an if/else statement. Basically "if this condition is met - the NSViewController becomes this size." Is there a way to change the dimensions of the NSViewController Frame or a way to do it with the initial Window Controller? I couldn't find anyone with the current correct syntax to do something like this.

Comment: `NSViewController` has no dimensions. Perhaps you mean the view or the window it's controlling?

Comment: The window, or view, or frame of the View Controller. - I think a lot of the problem is because I am utilizing full-screen, which is overriding my constraints. I want the fullscreen effect but with black around the edges - so I want to be able to set the dimensions. If that makes sense.

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense.  Why do you force your users to run your application with the fullScreen mode?

Comment: Hi Tomato - it's because the client doesn't want them to have access to the dock or anything on the front page while the application is running.